# Python with shell Command interaction

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess

Im trying to interact with a multiple shell program that one is written in python other in perl and other in ruby..

thought the terminal they run simple as a commands

```
$python demo.py

Option1
Option2
Option3
Option4

app1>1

#Menu 1 options
Option1 from menu 1
Option2 from menu 1
Option3 from menu 1
Option4 from menu 1

app1>2

#Option 2 from menu1 options
Option2.1 from menu 1
Option2.2 from menu 1
Option2.3 from menu 1
Option2.4 from menu 1

app1>2
```

All 3 apps run almost the same, but I try with php shell_exec command, python OS module and no one is able to interact with the submenus and the workflow of the program...

I'm able to run:

```
 import os   
 list = os.popen('pwd').read()
 print list
```

or

```
<?php shell_exec(´ls -las´)?>
```

Does any one have experience in migrating Shell programs without a GUI interface to a gui web interface?  (I was thinking of making like a wrapper to interact with this programs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the *subprocess module* to create the subprocess and then either interact with it using the *interact* method or the .stdin and .stdout attributes (which are file-like objects).

You have to pass stdin=subprocess.PIPE and stdout=subprocess.PIPE in the subprocess.Popen call, though, otherwise you will not be able to interact.

If you want to bind this to a web app or something, you'll additionally have to have it run "in the background", so that the user can interact with the program during multiple HTTP requests.

Comment: do you have any example or code to see how subprocess works ?